# jQuery check if an element is focused

Tags: jquery

I have a form with input and textarea, and I want to know if an element is focused.

I tried with something like:

```
if($('input').is(':focus')){
  alert('ok')
}
else{
  alert('nok')
}
```

I just need to know if an element on my page (input or textarea) are curently focused or not.

Thanks !

Comment: That's not working? [It appears to work for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/4qvghw5a/)

Comment: The code which you have posted should work

Comment: @Clement Andraud: You have iterate all the 'inputs' in the page then only u can get what is currently focussed

Comment: Why would you do that anyway? What's your goal? And, when (at what event) are you checking that? Would it not make more sense to listen for the `focusin` event on the element and then decide to perform some action when the event occurs?

Comment: I need to check that when i click on another button..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function(){
  //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use events for this:

```
$('input').on('focus', function(){
  // some code here
});

$('textarea').on('focus', function(){
  // some code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up event listeners when the page loads. And when the event occurs on any of those elements, some action would be performed.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.focus').on('focusin', function() {
        $('.output').val( this.tagName + ' HAS FOCUS' );
    })
    .on('focusout', function(e) {
        $('.focus:focus').length || $('.output').val( 'NO ELEMENT HAS FOCUS' );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
NAME: <input type="text" class="focus" name="fullname"/><br>
BIO:  <textarea name="bio" class="focus"></textarea><br><br>

STATUS: <input type="text" name="output" class="output" size="50" readonly="readonly" value="NO ELEMENT HAS FOCUS"/>
```